# Trying to add salts & keys as environment variables in elastic beanstalk (syntax error)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, syntax-error, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having some problems adding wordpress salts & keys as environment variables in elastic beanstalk (syntax error)

```
-bash: 1{: command not found
-bash: 8!~+w: command not found
-bash: br}P9^: No such file or directory
-bash: =:JDKbbfk: command not found
-bash: /etc/profile.d/eb_envvars.sh: line 11: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
-bash: /etc/profile.d/eb_envvars.sh: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Generated secret keys with : https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

[image]

Comment: The problem lies somewhere when AWS is trying to evaluate environment variables, but messes up the escaping of the characters used in shell commands. I'm struggling with the same thing trying to pass in an inline YAML array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary - use alphanumeric salts and keys.**

I'm following the [guide here](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/deploying-wordpress-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk.pdf) and it uses a YAML formatted file to define the salts and keys for WordPress. When creating a new environment, the environment variables are read and loaded correctly. However when it tries to launch the instances it chokes on the variables. I confirmed this when looking through the messages file from the instance logs.

Wondered if I was defining the YAML file correctly, but have seen a number of reports of similar problems. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231143/supervisord-in-docker-aws-elastic-beanstalk-cant-accept-non-alphanumeric-envi?rq=1) hits the nail on the head. So I replaced the keys and salts from the WordPress generator with ones [from here](http://passwordsgenerator.net/).

I set the password length to 64 and excluded symbols, included numbers, included lowercase characters, included uppercase characters, included similar characters, excluded ambiguous characters. It came up with strings like these:

```
S8TZaYb0dFL72A4ZwMKRxlUxmuwhq4UtLQhCCRR584SZ4XwIiQ0fIWu6WptauZ2V
b6wkMN2RtC0g67Wi2oHSYaDAZvyX2ECW98MiczoTHWKTxSK6s3bx9eLq9fkkqtKy
```

Basically just alphanumeric strings. Once I used those the instances started launching correctly and Elastic Beanstalk was a happy chappy.

So whatever is happening inside that instance requires alphanumeric keys and salts. Other characters may not work.