# Supervisord in Docker + AWS Elastic Beanstalk can't accept non-alphanumeric environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, supervisord

I am using custom Docker container in AWS Elastic beanstalk to deploy a wep application. I could set environment variables such as API key, API secret, etc.. on AWS web console.(Elastic beanstalk => Configuration => Software Configuration) It worked fine.

However, after I changed some variables to other values which contain special characters, it did not work with this error:

```
Docker container quit unexpectedly on Mon Oct 24 13:32:22 UTC 2016:
Error: Unexpected end of key/value pairs
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

Supervisord document says `Values containing non-alphanumeric characters should be quoted`.

My question is,

**Are there any ways to make environment variables with special characters, which is set from AWS elastic beanstalk, properly reach to a docker container by quoting them?**

I tried quoting them on web console:

[Double quoting env vars on web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gCvP.png)

But it did not work:

[Escaped the double quotes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMBTK.png)

AWS Elastic beanstalk escapes double quotes by default, I guess.

For more info. my ebextension config file:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    MY_VARIABLE: ""
    MY_VARIABLE_QUOTED: ""
```

Supervisord config file:

```
[program:run_app]
environment=MY_VARIABLE=%(ENV_MY_VARIABLE)s,MY_VARIABLE_QUOTED=%(ENV_MY_VARIABLE_QUOTED)s
command=gunicorn my_app.wsgi:application -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -t 300 --max-requests=100
directory=/var/www/my_app
user=root
stdout_logfile=/var/www/my_app/logs/django_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/www/my_app/logs/django_stderr.log
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopwaitsecs = 600
```

Comment: I just found some detour ways to solve those issues.

Comment: First, I created a shell script file `run_sv.sh`. The content of the file: `#!/bin/sh  MY_VARIABLE=\"${MY_VARIABLE}\" MY_VARIABLE_QUOTED=\"${MY_VARIABLE_QUOTED}\" supervisord -n -c /var/www/my_app/config/supervisor/test.conf`. It runs supervisord command with prepending variables wrapped by double quotes. Then, in Dockerfile, I added this line at the end: `CMD ["sh", "/var/www/my_app/conf/supervisor/run_sv.sh"]`